# background geolocation is not working in ionic 2

Tags: cordova, ionic2

I am using cordova-plugin-mauron85-background-geolocation plugin,it is working fine for foreground but not working in the background and I have tested my app is running in the background.
I have got the reference from http://www.joshmorony.com/adding-background-geolocation-to-an-ionic-2-application/

so how i can test app in background when our app is running in background i want to get current location in background ???

Answer (score 0):

I have had same issue, just as general,

1. enable debugging by setting `debug: true` in config object
2. be sure that you see the notfication bar in android when app is closed or is in background
3. if you have all above conditions, you should see some temporary notifications on your mobile screen

For me it was saying "Detecting STILL activity", which means I was sitting on same place for longtime developing the app, so I start moving and then it worked.

I don't know if is there any option to report location even if the user is STILL.

Comment: Hi thanks for your comment but i have facing this issue on ios in android its working fine .